# Find the relative depth of child folder

Tags: ruby

Given two paths, one parent and a child folder(or grandchild, grand-grandchild, etc), find the relative depth the child folder from the parent folder. It is always guaranteed that child folder is always present inside the parent folder and the paths always end with slash.

Example:

```rb
parent = "/home/user/path/parent/"
child = "/home/user/path/parent/g/g/child/"
#ans = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way to solve this will look like:

```rb
parent = '/home/user/path/parent/'
child = '/home/user/path/parent/g/g/child/'

# Split the paths
child_chunks = child.split(File::SEPARATOR).reject(&:empty?)
parent_chunks = parent.split(File::SEPARATOR).reject(&:empty?)

# Find the diff between the two lists
puts (child_chunks - parent_chunks).length # => 3
```

The better way though would be to use `Pathname` helper:

```rb
require 'pathname'

parent = Pathname.new('/home/user/path/parent/')
child = Pathname.new('/home/user/path/parent/g/g/child/')

puts child.relative_path_from(parent).to_s.split(File::SEPARATOR).length # => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def relative_depth(path1, path2)
  path2.count(File::SEPARATOR) - path1.count(File::SEPARATOR)
end
```

```
path1 = 'a/b/c/'
path2 = 'a/b/c/d/e/f/'

relative_depth(path1, path2)
  #=> 3
```

```
path3 = 'C:a\\b\\c\\'
path4 = 'C:a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\'
File::SEPARATOR = "\\" # simulate Windows

relative_depth(path3, path4)
  #=> 3
```

See [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-count).

[Demo](https://repl.it/@CarySwoveland/VagueTemporalScientists#main.rb)

Comment: Nice, but too complicated solution for a simple problem. `child.gsub(parent, "").split(File::SEPARATOR).length` yields the answer.

Comment: I like! Even better (because it does not create a temporary array): `child.gsub(parent, "").count(File::SEPARATOR)`. I encourage you to post that as an answer.